# BeautifulSoup extract script variable data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the name of this stock.

The variable is read from var followObjTitle.

URL: https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

with requests.Session() as c:

      nasdaq_baseurl = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'
      nasdaq_url = nasdaq_baseurl.__add__("AAPL")


      url_fetch = c.get(nasdaq_url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(url_fetch.text, 'html.parser')

      pattern = re.compile("var followObjTitle = '(.*?)';", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
      script = soup.find_all("script", text=pattern, type="text/javascript")
      name = soup.select('script')[]
      print(name)
```

My expected output is "Apple Inc."

How can select that specific variable to extract its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, BS is not intended to parse JavaScript. Use plain `re`. In your particular case, the line that you are looking for is `var followObjTitle = "Apple Inc.";`. Note that it uses double quotation marks, but your regex attempts to match single quotation marks. Finally, remove `re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL`, they have no business in your regex.

```
pattern = re.compile("var followObjTitle = \"(.*?)\";")
pattern.findall(soup.text)
#['Apple Inc.']
```